# In what ways is eternal inflation less certain than standard inflation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Eternal inflation is the idea that inflation could be eternal due to the effect of quantum fluctuations of the inflaton field.

Why do some cosmologists accept inflation, but consider eternal inflation much more speculative?

What are the added assumptions about eternal inflation that make it less certain than standard inflation? $~$ In what ways is eternal inflation more speculative than standard inflation?

Comment: It speculates on  the concept of accepting multiverses as real, which is something not easily adopted by people. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation